jmeter - getting error code 500 from working server
Hello, everyone!
I'm trying to do a JMeter load testing on a service and currently I'm stuck with getting error code 500 from a working server.
The cURL command I've used as a reference works fine - I'm getting an OK 200 response, but the JMeter test plan created with Tool -> Import from cURL doesn't.
Notes:

I send JMeter requests from a pod in a k8s-node to a remote server, the architecture looks as follows:

<my pod> --> <balancer with VIP(virtual IP)> --> <one of two HAProxy servers> --> <target service> 


Using Docker image alpine/jmeter, JMeter 5.6.3

What can be the cause of these errors?


Maybe import from cURL doesn't result in the same HTTP request, try comparing the requests originating from cURL and JMeter using a sniffer tool like Wireshark, it might be the case you're missing a header in the HTTP Header Manager or something like this

Another way of converting a cURL request into JMeter's HTTP Request sampler is using HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, it's possible to use JMeter as the proxy for cURL

And finally, HTTP status code 500 stands for internal server error, it worth checking server logs, you should be able to get more information or failure reason from there


